# Grad school, biology, funding?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

I am a student of biology at a State school in New York (SUNY), and my school is very liberal arts focused, I am also a racial minority.

I also have a poor GPA, 2.7ish currently, due to failings of a previous major(in computer science i received F's for 2 classes, and a D for one).

I am trying to do undergrad research, but only have 2 potential presentable results up and coming.

**Do grad schools typically fund students like me to get their tuition totally waived and a possible small stipend? What can I do to better my odds at securing such a position?** It is the only way I could even consider grad school.

Comment: Related: [How does the admissions process work for US Ph.D. programs, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-us-ph-d-programs-particularly-for-wea)

Comment: Most science PhD, and some master's, programs fund all or most students they accept.  Does this, together Mad Jack's link, answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most decent PhD programs in biology will guarantee 5 years of funding (tuition plus stipend on the order of 22K-30K / year) , with the provision that you may have to work as a teaching assistant 20 hours/week for some or all of that time.

The challenge will be getting into one of these programs with a 2.7 GPA. Many graduate schools require a minimum GPA, often around 3.0, for admission. Departments can and do petition to admit students with lower GPAs, but it certainly makes things harder. Being an underrepresented minority can be helpful *if* there are other strong aspects to your application that compensate in part for the low GPA.

As you've indicated, doing research is one possibility. Publishing a result would be great; simply being a lab for an extended period of time working alongside a PI is already a good thing. Why? It shows that you know what research is about, and it enables you to get a letter of recommendation from someone who knows you well in a research capacity.

What else can you do? Letters of recommendation are very important; do you know faculty from who you could get strong letters? If not, start making those connections now. A good GRE score will go a long way toward compensating for poor grades. It's worth preparing thoroughly for the GRE before you take it. Contacting possible advisors at the schools to which you are applying is extremely important. You can find lots of advice about how to go about doing that here on this site.

Good luck. While you're not in an optimal position, we've taken students with GPAs in your range at our top-20 PhD program, so certainly there is hope.